# Firebase Android getting a child value of a child value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Google Firebase to back an Android Application which has parties that include guest list.

I have my data structured to have the users have a child node with the party unique key and true/false, then the parties have a child node with user unique keys and true/false to show the relations.

```
users:
    [unique userKey]
        userName: coffeeAddict
        parties:
            [unique partyKey]: true
            [unique partyKey]: false
parties:
    [unique partyKey]: 
        partyName: Karen's 50th
        guests:
            [unique userKey]: true
            [unique userKey]: false
```

I followed what Firebase documentation shows as best practices, but my issue is I am trying to perform a query to get all the keys of the User's parties that are true. 
I have been able to query the database to get particular users and parties based on having a value like a username be equal to a set value.

The last query I tried which returns null is

```
DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.PARTIES);
Query userParty = database.orderByChild("guests/"+ userID).equalTo(true);
```

The main issue is I do not know how to check both sides are true and have a query based on that information. The goal is to create a list of a user's events based on their true/false status. Any help or guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: As a side note, ... there is no need to set a user- or partyKey value to false. Just delete the whole object ({"unique userKey" : false}), when you would set it to false. Then you can just listen to the whole guests/parties object. If this is not already solving your issue, please make yourself more clear what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I make here the assumption that you know which party you are querying for guests. Try this :

```
final List<String> attendees = new ArrayList<>();
Query userParty = database.child(uniquePartyId).child("guests").orderByKey().equalTo(true);
userParty.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        String userKey = dataSnapshot.getRef().toString();
        attendees.add(userKey);
    }
    ...
}
```

or

```
final List<String> attendees = new ArrayList<>();
Query userParty = database.child(uniquePartyId).child("guests").orderByKey();
userParty.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
        String userKey = dataSnapshot.getRef().toString();
        Boolean attendParty = (Boolean) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        if (attendParty) {
            attendees.add(userKey);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. The first function threw an error due to too many parameters on a query, but the second allowed me to get the users' key.